# Why can we instantiate multiple variables at once?

Tags: java, string, null, instantiation

After chasing down some `NullPointerException`s in a a recent project I finally found where they came from and it surprised me. Although I can now accurately describe where they came from and how to prevent them, I am still confused about how this kind of behavior can be allowed to happen without warning from the compiler or at least the IDE.

I had a browse around Stack and did some fairly extensive googling but can't find anything written about this. To cut to the chase here is some code demonstrating this odd behavior;

```
public class Test {

        String what, why, where = "who knows?";

        public static void main(String[] args) {         
           System.out.println("The 'what' String = " +new Test().what);
        }
    }
```

Output;

```
The 'what' String = null
```

This shows the correct output if you declare and instantiate each String separately, but chaining them together like this causes them to be instantiated `null`. So, the question is why? And if this is standard behavior, then why does the compiler even allow us to instantiate `String` objects this way?

Comment: `String what, why, where = "who knows?";`

It is similer to

    `String what;
    String why;
    String where = "who knows?";`

Comment: Warn you about what? You're declaring three variables and initializing one. Not an uncommon thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because internally it goes down to :

```
String what=null;
String why = null;
String where="who knows?"; // declaring 2 strings, only assigning the value to the third one.
```

Comment: Thanks. I've been programming excessively and extensively for more than a year now, and I never knew that you were only instantiating the last in the list. Just when you think you have the basics 100% down, something like this happens. Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 2):

`String what, why, where = "who knows?";` sets value only for the `where` variable, while the others are set to their default one, which is `null` (if they are class members, of course).

You can do the following: (assuming you want all of them to have the same value):

```
String what, why, where;
what = why = where = "who knows?"
```

Note that these two statements should be within a method, constructor or (static) initializer.

Answer (score 1):

That's equalant to following, only `where` get initialized to the given value `"who knows?"`, other set to default value `null`

```
String what;
String why;
String where="who knows?";
```

Try

```
String what, why, where;
what = why = where = "who knows?";
```